# Bird rip : routes should only be received

Tags: rip

My server should receive `routes` via `RIP`.
I have tried it with `Bird` on `Ubuntu 10.04`.
The server should work with the interface option `passive`.
(Receive routes and not send)

```
protocol kernel {
    persist;                
    scan time 20;
    export all;            
}

protocol device {
    scan time 10;           
}

protocol rip {
    export none;
    import all;
    interface "eth0" {
            passive yes;
    };
    debug all;
}
```

If I start bird, I get

```
bird: /etc/bird.conf, line 15: syntax error
```

Comment: Try deleting "yes" after passive.

Comment: The same result. I tried "yes", "true" and "".

Comment: Just tried this in lab. Doesn't work with version and passive statement. No ideas so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the bird version from the official repositorie (`bird 1.1.5-1`).
This version is very old and the option passive don't work.
I update bird to `1.6.3` and everything works.
Thanks to the BIRD Mailing List! (http://bird.network.cz/pipermail/bird-users/2017-March/011074.html)